# Is the positive power of a completely monotonic function also a completely monotonic function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

Can it be shown that if $f(x):[0,\infty)\to [0,1]$ is a completely monotonic function, then with $\alpha\geq0$, $(f(x))^{\alpha}$ is also completely monotonic? (It is the case at least when $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$).

I am not sure how to approach this problem. One property that we can use is that if $g(x)$ is a completely monotonic function and $h(x)$ is a Bernstein function, we can say that $g\circ h (x)$ is also completely monotonic. We know that $g(x)=x^{-\alpha}$, with $\alpha\geq0$ is completely monotonic. However, $h(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ need not be a Bernstein function, whenever $f(x)$ is completely monotonic ($x^{-2}$ is completely monotonic, but $x^{2}$ is not a Bernstein function).

Another approach I tried is to calculate the derivatives of $(f(x))^{\alpha}$ directly to see if they satisfy the definition of complete monotonicity. For instance, $(f^{\alpha})^{\prime} = \alpha f^{\alpha}f^{\prime}\leq 0$, and $(f^{\alpha})^{\prime\prime} = \alpha f^{\alpha-1}\left(f^{\prime\prime}+(\alpha-1)(f^{\prime})^2\right)$.

By choosing $\alpha\geq1$, we get $(f^{\alpha})^{\prime\prime}\geq 0$. However, when we proceed to $(f^{\alpha})^{\prime\prime\prime}$, it is not obvious what conditions on $\alpha$ would guarantee $(f^{\alpha})^{\prime\prime\prime}\leq 0$ (we see that $\alpha\geq 1$ is not sufficient).

Completely monotonic means: The $n$'th derivative of the function satisfies $(−1)^ n f^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$, $x \in (0, \infty)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already?

Comment: The question is actually nice and interesting. Please show some effort so it will not be closed.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding what I have tried already. I would appreciate any pointers on how to approach this problem.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen A typical example of a [completely monontone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions) function is $e^{-x}\,.$ The Bernstein-Hausdorff-Widder theorem characterizes those functions as Laplace transforms of positive Borel measures on $[0,+\infty)\,.$